# How to search standard library files in languages without include expressions?

Tags: ftplugin, include

[vim-apathy](https://github.com/tpope/vim-apathy) advertises the many possibilities of [`:h include-search`](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html#include-search).

However, if the programming language under consideration (here [GAP](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap4_mj.html)), does not have include expressions but the interpreter always loads a standard library [from a library path](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/tree/master/lib) and other packages with other means, are these languages excluded from this functionality?

Is it possible to explicitly add files, e.g. in an ftplugin, to the include search, so they are searched when one presses `[i`?

I was looking for something like

```
setlocal includedefaults+=$LIB/*.gd,$LIB/*.gi
```

or a vim function which can customize the include file list.

A plugin or NeoVim only solution would be good enough as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Include* search is done in the current and *included* files.

If your language doesn't let you explicitly include a file, then all Vim can do is search in the current file, which makes using *include* search rather pointless. That feature is simply not fit for your specific use case.

If you know where those packages are stored, then you might have more luck with `:help tags` and something like Universal Ctags, *if it supports your language*.

---

Now, [the documentation](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap76_mj.html#X825CBC5B86F8F811) mentions `LoadPackage()`, which can be considered like an "include":

```
" very raw, adjust to taste
setlocal include=LoadPackage
```

This might work if you set `:help 'path'` and `:help 'includeexpr'` properly,  to a list of default directories for the former, and to a function that returns a searchable path for the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1) I agree that without includes include-searches are more or less pointless. That is the reason for my question. 2) I am already using ctags as described [here](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/blob/master/etc/ctags.readme.md) and is helpful. I was wondering whether I could use the other mappings of include-search as well. 3) When writing a GAP package, you define required packages in a [PackageInfo.g](https://github.com/gap-packages/example/blob/master/PackageInfo.g#L282-L301) at the root of the project not in each file.

Comment: I think you can forget all about include-search for that language.

Comment: I will go with “forget about include-search for GAP”. IMHO, vim include mechanism could be extended to support also those languages. On a fresh system, there is no ctags and has to be configured similar to LSPs (does not exist for GAP either) and low-tech solutions can still help you to get around.

Comment: No include mechanism == no include search. But one could probably advocate a simpler "path search", I guess.

Comment: I read the doc more carefully. We can fake the include by using the `'include'` option but it will only provide one entry per match and you need as many as you have file to search in you standard library. It doesn't seems a fit to me anymore.